# SQL Server connection to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, poco

I'm trying to use POCO to connect to my database.

Whenever I try to connect, I get this error:

> Failed to load provider "System.Data.SqlClient".
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

NOTE: it's a local database, and remote access is enabled, TCP/IP is enabled, and the SQL Server service is running.

I'm using .NET Core 7

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Thank you all

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: And your connection string please

Comment: Hello, may I ask what method you use to connect to the database. If you use your own code to link to the database, is it convenient to share your code?